# Manipulate PDF iOS (add signature)

Tags: ios, pdf

I'm trying to find the best solution for my problem. User is using safari on an iPad, and at one point the customer contract is created using a webservice, which sends me the URL to a PDF file.
Right now the user opens the PDF, prints it and scans it after the customer signs the contract. What they want is to capture the signature digitally, so the contract doesn't need to be scanned later.
My question is: what is the best way to embed the signature to an existing pdf file?
I wanted something similar to what the iOS mail app does natively
http://heresthethingblog.com/2015/10/28/ios-9-tip-sign-pdf-mail-pdf-tricks/

Thanks

Comment: oh that's nice, is it open to developers yet? rolling your own would be doable, but a headache...